# boolean cannot be converted to int horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1));

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hello im trying to hide the horizontal recyclerview when vertical recyclerview scroll i have tried to implement this method but there  is an error

> boolean cannot be converted to int
> horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1));

```
verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setVisibility is required an integer, you can use `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`, but you give an boolean instead, If you want to hide it, change it to

```
verticalRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1))
               horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
               horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)) method doesn't take `boolean` param, which is returned by `canScrollVertically`. you have to set one of these params (`int`s)

> visibility    int: One of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE. Value is VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE

so

```
horizontalRecyclerView.setVisibility(recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1) ? 
    View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```